# How much is warpstone worth?

Tags: magic-items, equipment, pricing, wfrp-2e

Simply owning [warpstone](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Warpstone) is, of course, punishable by death in the Empire. But how much money should players receive if they managed to sell a piece weighing a few kg on the black market?

Comment: Hi, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, then check out the [help] or ask here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need further guidance. This is a good first question. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay Companion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1844163105) answers this question on page 44, illegal goods price list. Warpstone is worth 2000 gold coins per ounce.

Comment: Note: I'm not sure if it's a translation mistake but Polish version of the book states it's 2000 gold coins per POUND.